# Django post on click with jquery not getting a response

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am trying to setup a button on my website that when clicked a new model item is saved to the database. Segments of my code are pasted below and I will discuss the problem after.

textbook.html

```
<script src="../../static/textchange/wishlisting.js"></script>
```

...

```
<input type="button" id="addwishlist" value="Add to Wishlist"></input>
```

wishlisting.js

```
$('#addwishlist').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/textbook/',
    method: 'POST', // or another (GET), whatever you need
    data: {
        name: request.user,
        book: text, // data you need to pass to your function
        click: True
    }
    success: function (data) {
        // success callback
        // you can process data returned by function from views.py
    }
});
```

});

views.py

```
def textbook(request, uisbn):
    form4 = AddWishlist(request.POST or None)
    ltextbook = Textbook.objects.filter(isbn = uisbn)
    text = ltextbook[0]
    wishlists = Wishlist.objects.filter(textbook = text)
    listings = Posting.objects.filter(textbook = text)
    if request.POST.get('click', False):
        new = Wishlist(textbook = text, user = name, wish_date = datetime.now())
        new.save()
```

From my understanding when I click the "Add to Wishlist" button it should correlate that id with the id of the jquery referenced in wishlisting.html and then the view should be loaded and the database item should be made. What am I missing in my thought process?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your full view.

Comment: What is uisbn? something comming from url? Is that vew actually being executed? Put a `print 'debug'` at the beginning of the view to test.

Comment: uisbn is only used when i first go to the textbook view. I figured the post request wouldn't need it?

Comment: Did you put the `print`? I think this is not being executed because a parameter is missing. Try giving a default value for uisbn -> `def textbook(request, uisbn=None)`

Comment: If I just put a print("test") at the start of it it never prints, so im never reaching the view. That's with the usibn=None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes to begin:

1.) Use `staticfiles` to load files in templates:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

# You might need to change the path
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'textchange/wishlisting.js' %}"></script>
```

2.) Get used to CamelCase:

```
<input type="button" id="addWishList" value="Add to Wishlist" uisbn="set_value_here"></input>
```

To answer your question:

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

from datetime import datetime


@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def textbook(request):
    uisbn = request.POST.get('uisbn')
    # I'm assuming all of this is correct
    ltextbook = get_object_or_404(Textbook, isbn=uisbn)
    if ltextbook:
        text = ltextbook[0]
        wishlists = Wishlist.objects.filter(textbook=text)
        listings = Posting.objects.filter(textbook=text)
        new = Wishlist(textbook=text, user=request.user, wish_date=datetime.now())
        new.save()
        new_created = True
    else:
        new_created = False

    data = {
        'new_created': new_created
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**html:**

```
$('#addWishList').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // Use the name of the url not '/textbook/'
        url: "{% url 'textbook' %}",
        data: {
            "uisbn": $(this).attr("uisbn"),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.new_created) {
                // Do something here
            } else {
                // Do something else here
            }
        },
        error: function (rs, e) {
            alert('Sorry, there was an error.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, all very helpful.

Comment: @joe Anytime! Best of luck (: